# Latent Variable Models such as Harrison and Rutstrom (2008)

Tags: econometrics, reference-request

I'm working with some experimental data on choice under uncertainty and trying to use a method similar to RISK AVERSION IN THE LABORATORY ([Harrison and Rutstrom, 2008](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.469.509&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

I am pretty sure that one of the explanatory variables used to estimate the  $\mu$ and CRRA parameter is an upper bound.  Does anyone have a good link to some literature on these kinds of latent variable models with errors in variables with a known distribution, e.g., gamma?